# AngularJS and "this" alias

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm tasked with updating another person's AngularJS (version 1) code.  In a Javascript file, for the app.directive() section's controller function I see a "this" alias:

```
   app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: contextPath + "myPath/myDirective.html",
        controllerAs: 'myDirectiveCtrl',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $http, $rootScope) {
            var ctrl = this;
            ...
```

I understand that "ctrl" is a way for the functions to reliably refer to "this" even after the constructor has completed.  However, later on I see this code:

```
this.someFunction = function() {                    
    this.firstProperty = true;
    this.secondProperty = true;
    ...
    ctrl.thirdProperty = [];
    ...
```

In my understanding the "this." code would be wrong as the function can't guarantee the accuracy of "this.", so I'm tempted to "fix" the code so that all of these properties use "ctrl."

Is my reasoning right?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: What is the function that is being called in? Are they passing ctrl into the function and then calling ctrl.thirdParty array? The "this" is referring to the the object that is being passed into the function. This definitely looks like a code smell. I would change this code but without seeing how the rest of the function is working I can't suggest any fixes.

Comment: For controller methods that are called in template this is redundant, because they are referred as `controllerAsIdentifier.someFunction()` and don't lose their context. If the method isn't called but passed as a callback somewhere and loses its context, it is valid, however, a cleaner way is to use `bind` on such methods.